# Best way to do many to many relation on the same table

Tags: sql-server

I want to implement a new function in my app in order to link a file with other files (many to many relation). I thought that the best solution is create a "RelationTable" that contains duplicate fileId pairs. I mean:

**RelationTable**

```
FileX FileY

file1 file2
file2 file1
file3 file4
file4 file3
file5 file2
file2 file5
```

To see all files linked to "File2" I would make this query:

```
select * from RelationTable
where FileX = file2
```

My question is, this is the best solution? are there other ways to improve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can `file2` link to many files as well?

Comment: Hi! thank you for your response. Yes, file2 could be linked to other files

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Are your mappings always bidirectional?

Comment: Yes, If file2 is linked to file1, file1 must be linked to file2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can use your solution, just index the table properly:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX -- or ALTER TABLE ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        ux_relationTable_X_Y
ON      relationTable (fileX, fileY);

CREATE INDEX
        ix_relationTable_Y
ON      relationTable (fileY);
```

**Update:**

As you are using SQL Server, you can run accross edge cases with trailing blanks, which are trimmed on insert but can be meaningful in filenames.

**Update 2:**

If your mappings are always bidirectional, do not create the second index (on `fileY`), it's redundant.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, of course. This new table will  contain a big number of rows. That is the reason why I thought if this is the best solution.

Comment: RelationTable will contain File Id's ;)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using a `CASE` and then you don't need to have two rows for each biderectionnal relationship:

```
select file2 as X,
       (CASE WHEN fileX = file2 
           THEN fileY 
           ELSE fileX
        END) as Y 
from RelationTable 
where (fileX=file2 or fileY=file2);
```

to fetch all files related to file2

On a table like this

```
fileX    fileY
--------------
file2     file1
file3     file2
```

The result will be

```
X        Y
---------------
file2    file1
file2    file3
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will do it ;)